# PHP exec isn't running the command but rather giving a strange output

Tags: php

This was working, on CentOS 6, now I keep getting some strange output from exec()

```
exec("nohup php " . FCPATH . "import.php 2>&1",$output);
echo '<pre>';die(print_r($output));
```

This is calling a file /home/SITE/public_html/import.php

But the $output array has "Status: 302 Moved Temporarily" in key 0, rather than running the actual script.

If I run the same command in shell it works perfectly fine, I can't understand why it's saying 302 from php.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: It seems that the import.php script is trying to fetch something from an URL. 302 is a HTTP response, and nothing in the snippet you posted would render any HTTP response.

Comment: i actually found the problem, i needed to use the full path to PHP, sorted it right away!